# tkinter, multiple top level windows

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, toplevel

I am new in tkinter. I want create main menu, after I click button PLAY, it should create new window with bunch of buttons. Each button in this new window should create another window (and close actual window). But my problem is that If I click button PLAY, it will open all windows.

```
from tkinter import *


class Choices:

    def __init__(self, master):
        root.minsize(width=False, height=False)
        root['bg'] = 'forest green'
        self.master = master
        b_color = 'red'
        b_width = 30
        b_height = 4
        b_pady = 10
        self.headline = Label(self.master, text='Welcome to Casino', bg='forest green', font=('broadway', 30))
        self.headline.grid()
        self.buttons_frame = Frame(master, bg='forest green')
        self.buttons_frame.grid()
        self.b_play = Button(self.buttons_frame, text='PLAY', bg=b_color, width=b_width, height=b_height, command=self.play)
        self.b_play.grid(pady=b_pady)
        self.b_credits = Button(self.buttons_frame, text='CREDITS', bg=b_color, width=b_width, height=b_height)
        self.b_credits.grid(pady=b_pady)
        self.b_quit = Button(self.buttons_frame, text='QUIT', command=root.quit, bg=b_color, width=b_width,
                             height=b_height)
        self.b_quit.grid(pady=b_pady)

    def play(self):
        root.withdraw()
        self.pick = Toplevel(self.master)
        self.game = GamePick(self.pick)


class GamePick:

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.buttons_frame = Frame(self.master)
        self.buttons_frame.grid()
        b_jack = Button(self.buttons_frame, text='Black Jack', bg='snow4', command=self.do_black_jack())
        b_jack.grid()


    def do_black_jack(self):
        root.withdraw()
        self.var_bj = Toplevel(self.master)
        self.open_bj = BlackJack(self.var_bj)


class BlackJack:

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        label = Label(self.master, bg='green', text='It is working')
        label.grid()

root = Tk()
my = Choices(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

To resolve your problem:

In the `__init__()` of `GamePick()` class, change this line of code:

```
b_jack = Button(self.buttons_frame, text='Black Jack', bg='snow4', command=self.do_black_jack())
```

To:

```
b_jack = Button(self.buttons_frame, text='Black Jack', bg='snow4', command=self.do_black_jack)
```

What we did is simply to remove `()` from `command = self.do_black_jack()`

Comment: Reason for the downvote? My answer is correct and I tested the OP's program on my machine.